# rtsp поток в rtmp debian

Tags: apache, nginx, debian, rtmp, rtsp

У меня есть поток rtsp с камеры. я хочу вывести это видео на сайте. Для этого, как я понял, его надо перевести в rtmp. Я установил модуль для nginx (нашел такую инструкцию), но у меня не заработало. Думаю, что проблема в том, что у меня на сервере связка nginx+apache. Может кто знает какие то другие способы? или в чем может быть тут проблема?

P.S. Никаких ошибок не выдается, но rtmp не работает

Comment: посмотрите, как отображение картинки с видеокамер реализовано в, например, [zoneminder](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=zoneminder&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all).

Comment: спасибо, но мне надо не готовое решение, а серверная программа, которая сможет rtsp переделать в rtmp

Comment: насколько я вижу, zoneminder умеет отображать именно rtsp и именно на сайте. потому всего лишь предложил посмотреть — как они это сделали.

Comment: мне надо что то типа этого - https://www.dmosk.ru/instruktions.php?object=nginx-rtmp, но у меня не работает по этой инструкции